# Why is my Google bookmarks in Polish?

Tags: localization, google-bookmarks

I am using Google from Germany, occasionally I get it in German, but once I log in it goes back to English, as from my setup.

Today, as a logged in user, I performed a search of "Google bookmarks", I clicked the result, and the page contained my bookmarks, but it was localized in Polish. Does anybody have an idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Because google uses geolocation. If you have default EN browser and Polish locale and UK timezone while in germany it will simply vary between them

Comment: Well that would make sense if I had polish locale, which I have not. Also, all the computers in the lab behaved in the exact same way, regardless of operating system or browser.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Google pages can be forced to show up in a given locale just using an additional parameter (hl) on the URL Just like this (change *en* for the desired language):

> http://www.google.com/?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser's options.  Go to managing Cookies then search and delete cookies relating to "google".  This should reset your settings.

Answer (score 0):

your ISP (internet service provider) might have given you an external IP that is in poland or close, check with whatismyip.com's [what my ip says about me](https://www.whatismyip.com/what-my-ip-says-about-me/?iref=home)